# How to put slash "/" in between two integers?

Tags: android

I am trying to show result for my quiz app and I want to show result something like 5/10 but currently I'm just showing Correct Answers.
My question is I'm trying to show both `correct answers` as well as `total question` and `Slash` "/" in between correct answers and total question .
Here is my code.

```
rightans = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("rightans").toString();
        totalquestions = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("totalques")
                .toString();

        numberques = Integer.parseInt(totalquestions);

        rightanswer = Integer.parseInt(rightans);

        result = (rightanswer);
```

Comment: try result = rightanswer +"/" +numberques  ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a TextView for this.

```
txtright = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtright);
```

And after That define whatever you want to do something like.

```
txtright.setText("" + result + "/" + "" + numberques);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem.

```
result = String.format("%d/%d",rightanswer,numberques);
```